# Manipulating a session array of hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The following session data has an array of hashes that is dynamically named

```
session["a_#{@aisle.id}"] = [{"id"=>"26", "name"=>"skis", "sale_price"=>"449.99"}, {:id=>"17", :name=>"Boots", :sale_price=>"146.42"}]
```

To display these, in a view, `session["a_#{@aisle.id}"].each` can call each member of the collection, however how should these members be invoked?

```
session["a_#{@aisle.id}"].each do |hash|
  hash.sale_price
end
```

will return `(undefined method 'sale_price' for #<Hash:0x00007feb9b090338>)`.

Subsequently, how should the sum of `sale_price` key be called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you just need to use the `[key]` hash accessor. You can find the sum like so:

```
sum = session["a_#{@aisle.id}"].sum do |hash|
  hash["sale_price"]
end
```

or alterntively you could do this with `map` + `sum`:

```
prices = session["a_#{@aisle.id}"].map do |hash|
  hash["sale_price"]
end
sum = prices.sum
```